# How to convert gif file to xml file

Tags: gif

What to do convert  my **gif file to xml file**.  I have animated GIF file contain 179 frames!!! I try to create xml  file from this GIF file.Possible automatic convert GIF to xml.Tanks strong text

Comment: Did you try to use software to convert it to XML?

Comment: i don't find software for this!!